# Show that there is an identity element with respect to the operation $+$ and every subset $A$ of $D$ has an inverse with respect to $+$

Tags: proof-verification, binary-operations

> Let $P_D$ be a power set of $D$.
>
> The operation $+$ is to be regarded as an operation on $P_D$.
>
> Show that there is an identity element with respect to the operation $+$ and every subset $A$ of $D$ has an inverse with respect to $+$.

Let $A * B = A + B.$

$A * e = A + e = A$. Then  $e = 0$ which is an identity for $+$.

$A * A' = A + A' = e.$ Then $A' = - A$. Thus, $A' * A = - A + A = 0.$ So, the inverse exists.

Checking to see if that's correct.

Comment: You haven’t told us what the operation $+$ is.

Comment: Not sure if that's it, but this problem starts with the definition of symmetric difference $A + B = (A - B) \cup (B - A)$ If that's the definition of $+$, I guess I am gonna have to redo this problem.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra If the definition is the one above, then you need to redo it.

Comment: Let $A * B = A + B = (A - B) \cup (B - A).$

$A * e = (A - e) \cup (e - A) = A$. Let $e = \{\}.$ Then $A - e = A \text { and } e - A = \{\}.$ Thus, $A \cup \{\} = A.$ Identity exists. 

$A * A' = (A - A') \cup (A' - A) = e$. Let $A' = A$. Then the union $(A - A') \cup (A' - A)$ will be empty. Inverse exists.  Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your proof assumes that $*$, which you've defined to be equal to $+$, is a group operation - but you never used any properties of $+$ and your proof would equally well establish that every binary operation on any power set is a group - which is false.

You need to expand $+$ as a symmetric difference, if that is what it is defined as and prove these things.

Comment: I redid my work in the comments above. I took identity to be the empty set and the inverse of a set $A$ to be $A$. Please, see if that's correct.

Comment: @Abstrakt Yes, that works. It's really confusing how you're writing it out, though. It would be far clearer to write something like $$A+\{\}=(A-\{\})\cup (\{\}-A\{\})=A\cup\{\}=A$$ to show that $\{\}$ is the identity and $$A+A=(A-A)\cup(A-A)=\{\}\cup\{\}=\{\}$$ to show that $A$ is the inverse of $A$ - certainly it makes little sense to talk about an operation $*$ which you've defined to be exactly the same as $+$.